# Precognitive and Beta Badges

Tags: discussion, badges

Is it possible to get the Precognitive and Beta badges still? The description states you must follow "this site" before private beta. If that's the case, why isn't it "retired" like the Analytical badge?

Answer (score 2):

The badges page is general for all network sites and there are still sites going through the site proposal process on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Yes, it's impossible to get this badge for any sites that are past this point, it's still *generally* possible to get, just not on SO or the currently non-private beta sites... in fact, since SO never went through the Area 51 process, no one will ever have the [Precognitive badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

You ask why they can't customize it to the site... my understanding is that, other than the count of users who have a badge, the page is rendered the same on all sites. Customizing the badges list on a per-site basis would mean having to update several versions of the page depending on what state the site is in. For simplicity, they only move badges to the "retired" section when it's impossible to get the badge anywhere on the network any more.

Comment: reeeeally. nobody has this badge?? why do they leave it in the badge list then? to tease us?

Comment: @Tom wait, John skeet will get this badge after hitting 2M ... we will travel in the past to make SO in the Area 51 then bring the badge. That's why it's kept in the list